# connected and intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a connected subset of the reals. Then all the continuous functions on S satisfies the intermediate value theorem.

Is this correct? I am sure it is not when we use the version of IVT from Wikipedia with f(a) and f(b). But when I use the below version, I got a bit confused. Thank you very much! [image: l]

Comment: What does it mean for a continuous function on $[0,1)$ to satisfy the IVT? This has to be said. Otherwise the task is not doable.

Comment: I think this is why I am considering the max min value version of IVT?

Comment: But for $\frac 1x$ on $(0,1]$ there is no max.

Comment: i am not even sure if these two versions are equivalent!

Comment: They are.......

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? Do you understand what the quoted theorem is saying? It implies your version since if $f(a) \leq y\leq b$ then of course $m\leq f(a)\leq y\leq f(b)\leq M$, so there is $c\in[a,b]$ with $f(c)=y$, right?

Comment: they are ?I didn't find any repetition online of this version. I found it in a textbook.

Comment: Maybe the version you need says that given $a, b \in Im(f)$ with $a < b$ then for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$, $a < y < b$,  there exists $x \in Dom(f)$ such that $f(x) = y$, does it?

Comment: The main question is: where did you get the claim from which is to prove?

Comment: @ amsmath  it's a GRE question. So they are equivalent, you are saying?

Comment: Here is a question which may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663112/prove-x-is-connected-iff-for-every-continuous-fx-rightarrow-mathbb-r?rq=1 Just replace $X = S$ if you are not familiar with metric spaces.